# «Почему? — сейчас расскажу» — корректно?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно так:

`Почему — сейчас расскажу`.

Можно так:

`Почему? Сейчас расскажу`.

А сразу два знака допустимо?

`Почему? — сейчас расскажу`.

Comment: Можно когда? Какой контекст? Насчёт "Почему? — сейчас расскажу." - или третий знак поставь, или один убери. Предложение с маленькой буквы и тирешечка длинная - это перебор.

Comment: @Буратино Лично я не уверен, с маленькой писать или с большой. Если так вообще можно.

Comment: Но ты тем не менее так написал, и по-другому, значит смог? Где логика? Вопрос не можно ли так или сяк, а можно так где? когда? а когда нельзя? В твоём вопросе отсутствует обстоятельство задачи, условие, только вероятные ответы, не ясно на чём базирующиеся. Ты составил некий тест, а теперь спрашиваешь, какой вариант правильный? Может и не какой, а может всё, ты его составлял, тебе и правило выбирать, если нет иных условий.